# How to change color of desktop "Selection Box" ? "Not Duplicate"

Tags: gnome, themes, notification, colors

First Picture. The Desktop "Selection Box"

### [image]

As You see in this picture, the color is brown same as my notification bubble, whereas the "selected" item color is the same with my theme. But notification color can be changed with some tools called NotifyOSD so not a problem there.

---

### Second Picture. In Windows "Selection Box"

[image]

Window color "selection box" is the same with my theme and "selected icon" also the same with my theme.

Comment: Oh yeah Btw, i am using ubuntu 15.04